# changing the next and previous arrow key in bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I am making a bootstrap carousel, and it is ok. it is like this:

[image]

the next and previous arrow key is like above.

```
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
       <span class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
       <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
```

and css is :

```
.carousel-control-next:after {
   content: '>';
   font-size: 25px;
   color: black;
   font-weight: bold;
}
.carousel-control-prev:after {
   content: '<';
   font-size: 25px;
   color: black;
   font-weight:bold;
}
```

but I want to change it to this arrow key like this:

[image]

the next and previous are arrow keys image of my own. how can I do that:

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will work, I haven't used BS for quite a bit of time...

```
arrowsParentEl {
   position: relative;
}

.carousel-control-next:after {
   content: '>';
   font-size: 25px;
   color: black;
   font-weight: bold;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
}

.carousel-control-prev:after {
   content: '<';
   font-size: 25px;
   color: black;
   font-weight:bold;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
}
```